# Excel Formula: Return range of True and False Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a named range, returning values of 0 and >0.

I need to substitute the values in this range as follows:
0 = FALSE, more than 0 = TRUE

Say my range is A1:A10, with values:

- 0, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.36, 0, 0

What I need returned:

- FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE

I've tried wrapping the indirect function inside the AND() function to perform the logical test, but this did not work.

Comment: Use an IF formula

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel with Dynamic Arrays, you can merely enter:

```
B1:  =A1:A10>0
```

If not, you can enter it as an array over b1:b10 with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

*If you want the results displayed differently, please be explicit*

[image]

Comment: I tried adding '>0' to my named range, but this breaks the sumproduct formula I'm using the named range within

Comment: This answers the question you asked.  As is often the result when you pose an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), it doesn't address your actual problem. I suggest you formulate a different question that addresses the problem you **really** have.

Comment: I need sumproduct to receive a named range with True / False values instead of 0's and values slightly >0. Within the 'Name Manager' do you know of a function I can wrap my named range in, that will convert my range objects from numeric values into boolean values, per the context of the logical test?

Comment: @Kopite833 As I suggested, I think you need to ask another question. If you define `myRange` to refer to: `A1:A10`, then `myRange>0` will return an array of `{TRUE,FALSE..}` depending on the contents of `A1:A10`.  But comments are not the place to ask a new question. I really suggest you close this question by accepting one of the answers, and then formulate a question with your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 =IF(A1=0,"false","true")
```

Comment: The formula is being performed in a named range and I need to return the whole range

Comment: Not sure I understand, sorry. If a table, then it would look like: =IF([@columnname]=0,"false","true")

Answer (score 0):

Hey what I  would is is write some lines in VBA and save the excel as macro enabled. This way even if you have 1.000.000 lines it will automatically do what you 'd like!

```
Public Sub truefalse()
      Dim Lastrow As Long
      Lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To Lastrow
       If Range("A" & i).Value > 0 Then
       Range("B" & i).Value = "true"
    Else
       Range("B" & i).Value = "False"
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but looking for a solution within excel

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you named range name is `MyData` then use below formula then drag and down.

```
=MyData>0
```

[image]

Comment: This is the solution but perhaps not the desired presentation. @Kopite833 please enter `=(MyData > 0)` in a cell and see the result in a sheet where the named range exists and is filled with numbers. It should be what you want, and you can build the snippet into any formula, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find solution to particular problem, developed workaround to fulfil purpose